# Grub menu at boot time... "holding shift" not working

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I read here at [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) that holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot can bring up the GRUB menu. However I try holding one or the other <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys, tapping, tapping then holding, nothing works. Am I missing something? How does one access the GRUB menu during boot time?

No dual boot here, just standard Lubuntu 14.04 install.

Comment: It depends on the hardware. Sometimes ESC works.

Comment: Gave ESC a try too. That key is used by my BIOS to enter its settings menu. I tried ESC after the BIOS splash screen just before the Ubuntu splash but no luck either. I just can't seem to get in there on this machine (ASUS X200M). No problem with other machines.

Comment: Another factor would be timing to press. Press and hold `Esc` key after the BIOS splash screen worked for me. Pressing earlier would land me to CSM screen (since I have disabled Secure boot). I can just suggest timing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Answer (score 28):

I also cannot access the GRUB menu by any manner of pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd> on my Asus X205TA. To get the GRUB menu to display at boot, I had to modify the `/etc/default/grub` file. See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup).

To get the GRUB menu to display every time (until I change it back) I used nano to edit the file in the terminal. Type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line that says `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` or `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`
put `#` at the start of this line to comment it out

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

or

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

**and make sure `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` or some other number bigger than zero.** When done exit nano saving changes and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I'm very late getting back to this, but this worked for me too, thank you!

Comment: Just commenting since I tried this: something may have been updated since this doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 18.04). My `/etc/default/grub` didn't have a `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` line, however this may have been replaced by `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`. Should I replace that with something else to mimic your solution, and do you know what that should be?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon thank you for the extremely helpful comment! Every time the package maintainer has changed the `/etc/default/grub` file I have kept my edited version (because I use many boot parameters as well as forcing the GRUB menu to appear). Thanks to you I checked the new version and tested it, and updated my answer here. [This version](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HnK8X2yGPk/) forces the menu successfully. Now I just need to try to find all the places where I mentioned this and correct those too O.O

Answer (score 11):

I have an X200MA. To enter the GRUB menu, you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> while booting. Choose `Ubuntu` to boot normally.

You may have problems if you installed Ubuntu not in UEFI mode. I did not test it that way.

Comment: shift wasn't working for me, esc did work. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The system would boot directly and my monitor would be in out-of-range mode. I pressed <kbd>↑</kbd> repeatedly until I thought GRUB was waiting for a command, then I pressed <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> to select recovery mode.

It took a few tries or randomness, but when I entered recovery mode the display came back. I then:

1. Selected root for a root prompt
2. Ran `mount -o rw,remount /` to mount the filesystem in read-write mode
3. Ran `vi /etc/default/grub`
4. Removed `#` from `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`
5. Saved the file
6. Ran `update-grub` to update GRUB
7. Ran `exit` to return to the menu and continue booting

GRUB would show up, the monitor would work, and then I could log in.

Comment: uncommenting `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` worked for me too, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this question in hope that it will help someone else in the Future.

Usually you are right in trying to get to Grub with <kbd>Shift</kbd>! But Grub usually explicitly prohibits using the Shift key if you have "Fastboot" enabled:

```
if [ "\${fastboot}" = "1" ]; then
  # timeout_style=menu + timeout=0 avoids the countdown code keypress check
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=0
```

*Taken from /etc/grub.d/12_menu_auto_hide*

But the other people who answered in here are right aswell, but I think for a different problem. If the Grub menu does not start automatically on start up, you can try fiddeling with your /etc/default/grub file.

Open it with sudo rights:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And there you should see two entries of importance to us:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT= "some number, probably 0 or 5"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE= hidden/menu/countdown
```

GRUB_TIMEOUT tells us how long Grub will wait for Input until it loads the default OS.

- 0 will instantly choose the default OS
- -1 will wait on user input indefinitely

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE tells you how the Grub menu is shown, if at all

- hidden= Hides grub unless you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> in time
- menu= Will show Grub
- countdown= Will not show grub, but an actual Countdown
  on screen

Hope that helped
(more info on the other entries in /etc/default/grub [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Konfiguration/)

Comment: Not helpful if you can't get into your system in the first place

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues that make getting into the grub menu difficult on some systems.

- The timing of when to hit a key to abort the hidden menu feature is tricky
- Holding down the shift key doesn't always work because some bioses will think the key is stuck and clear it or give an error on stuck key
- Some video cards will not be initialized yet when the menu should come up, and the screen will be black, causing you to miss it

The first two problems can be bypassed by using capslock instead of shift.
The trick is to press caps lock during boot and watch the capslock light.  When it goes out, hit capslock again to turn it back on, and keep doing that until either you get the grub menu or you realize you've missed the timing again.

Once you've gotten past the hidden menu and gotten the grub menu, you need to turn off capslock and then interact with the menu before the menu timeout occurs and it selects the default item.

If you have a system with timing issues or video card initialization issues with grub, I strongly recommend you use one of the other answers here to permanently disable the hidden menu feature and/or force text console mode, as appropriate.  You will need to either boot successfully to do this -- either normally, via rescue options in the grub menu, or by booting the Ubuntu install media and invoking rescue mode from there.

When I'm installing ubuntu on a machine that has known problems like this, I'll use the "try ubuntu before installing" option and before it finishes, edit /etc/default/grub to disable hidden menu.   This can be done during install or before rebooting at the end.  Make sure update-grub gets rerun after you make that edit, either as part of the install or manually.

Answer (score 0):

##### Simple answer:

In the file **`/etc/default/grub`**, set **`GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`**, not `0`. (Or set it to some other positive number, which is interpreted as seconds.) Then run **`sudo update-grub`** after saving the edit.

##### Terminal one-liner to do this:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^.*GRUB_TIMEOUT=.*$/GRUB_TIMEOUT=1/' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if it included GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

Comment: The shift key will still work (for x seconds) even if the menu is hidden, pressing which, will show the menu. This is a discreet way of not seeing the menu in each and every boot while having the capacity to interrupt and load Grub selection.